# Recommendations for Rest Api for remote hosting

Tags: android, web, rest, web-apis

I have been working on an Android app, wanted to host a Rest Api on remote server to get daily data for customer. Can you tell me about any services which doesn't cost much and can be used?

I have been doing some research and found out about Amazon web services and Google cloud Services, Firebase. But the prices are quite high.

Can anyone recommend me the possibility if I have to just pass on a sentence each day to all the app users. The no of apps which can be using the same data can be around 10-100. The no of calls is one of the main factor I am looking at.

Any database, Mysql, Mongodb, etc will not be a problem for me. I just don't think that using a high level database for a very small data is efficient.

It would be helpful if anyone can direct me to any services, or architectures for remote hosting where the no of calls are quite large.

Comment: Been a happy linode.com customer for almost 15 years, you have full root access and total control.

Comment: Not sure if you have seen Firebase Cloud Functions which is free for small projects and provides a limited quota for calls to the functions you make

Comment: Linode looks like a very good option. Quota for calls is the main problem I am facing that is why I didn't want to use Firebase. Firebase is has good support in android, hope they make the quota of calls a little more. Thank you for the suggestions.